# create list of strings more easily

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

Every time I need to create a list of strings in python or another language with similar list syntax (and they more or less the same everywhere) I have to do the following.

```
# resulting expression
a = ('word1', 'word2', 'word3')

#cursor is between the parenthesis
a = (|)
```

type `'word1<ESC>a,` etc for each word. I don't have to type single quote twice, because I'm using delimitmate, but I have to use esc to move cursor out of the quotes.
There is a better way to do it.
What if I would type

```
a = (word1 word2 word3)
```

instead and then use regex to surround all words inside parens with quotes and add comma after that? This would save me 3 key strokes for each word if I would remap this to some key.
The problem is I don't know how to do this replacement via regex.
So the best I've got so far is

```
:s/\v\((.*)\)/\=substitute(submatch(0) ....
```

The dots in the end is because I need to replace it with backreference in substitute, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: If you do type the single quote twice, does it have the effect of moving the cursor to the other side of the auto-inserted quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ('word1', 'word2', 'word3')
```

Technically, that's a tuple. :)

Now, for the `substitute()` command, it depends on what the strings can contain. If they don't contain any whitespace, you can match non-whitespace characters with `\S`:

```
:s/(\zs.*\ze)/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\S\+', "'&',", 'g')/
```

This will leave a trailing comma, which shouldn't be a problem. You could also use `\w` for word-characters, `\i` for characters allowed in identifiers, etc. I have modified your expression to leave out the parentheses in the matched text - they don't belong in the strings and complicating the second pattern for handling them is unnecessary.

Similarly, you can use a delimiting character that won't appear in the strings (think CSV), then use all-but-that-character in the `substitute()` pattern (`,` and `[^,]`, for example).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37574/discussion-between-user1685095-and-muru).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a macro:

Once you have:

```
a = (word1 word2 word3)
```

Go on the `(` character with for example <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>(</kbd>

Then record this macro: `qqwi'<Esc>ea',<Esc>q`

- `qq` start recording in register `q`
- `w` go to the next word
- `i'<esc>` insert a `'` before the word and leave insert mode
- `e` go to the end of the word
- `a',<Esc>` append a `',` after the word and leave insert mode
- `q` stop recording the macro

You can then replay the macro as many time as you have words in the list: here it would be `2@q`.

This also leave would with a trailing coma that you'll have to remove.